# Owl carousel spits out a single item instead of a carousel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, owl-carousel

I am trying to make a carousel that shows a list of new tutors in a specific area from latest first. I am using laravel 5.6, vue.js and owl carousel.

Below I am using axios to retrieve from the database, and call owl-carousel

```
<script>
      export default {
    props: {
      areaId: null,
    },

    data () {
      return {
        NewTutors: {}
      }
    },

    methods: {
      getNewTutor () {
        var that = this;
        axios.get( '/' + this.areaId + '/home/new').then((response) => {
          that.NewTutorss = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
          this.errored = true
        });
      }
    },

    mounted () {
      this.getNewTutor();
    }
  }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#NewHustles').owlCarousel();
    });

</script>
```

and here and try and loop through each new tutor in a carousel.

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded" id="NewTutors">

    <div class="owl-stage-outer">

        <div class="owl-stage">


            <div class="owl-item" v-for="NewTutor in NewTutors>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        {{NewTutor.name}}
                    </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div>
                    {{NewTutor.area.name}}
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    Image goes here
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    {{NewTutor.user.first_name}}
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I get all the cards, with the correct data passed through, but instead of a single row carousel, I get a big blob of cards that move as if there was only one item. I have tried Vue.nexttick, and playing around with a few other things, but nothing seems to work quite right.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `owl-item` class on the `v-for` div instead of on the child?  I'm guessing it's expecting a specific structure to work properly

Comment: Yes, it was like that just before I posted the question. Made no difference.